# Decomposing positive semidefinite matrices into some other positive semidefinite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

let $W \in \mathbb{C}^{L\times L}$ be positive semidefinite and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times L}$. For which $B$ is it so that for any $W$ there is an $E \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ positive semidefinite so that $W = B^\star E B$.

Note that here positive semidefinite also implies symmetric.

I'm thinking $B$ must have rank $\min\{N,L\}$ and tried things like eigendecomposition of W or rewriting $W = A^\star A$ for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times L}$ to no result. I feel like I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $B$ has full column rank.

For necessity, when $W=I$ we have $B^\ast EB=I$ for some $E$. Hence $(Bx)^\ast E(Bx)=\|x\|^2>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$. Thus $Bx\ne0$ whenever $x\ne0$, meaning that $B$ has full column rank.

For sufficiency, when $B$ has full column rank, it has a left inverse $A\in \mathbb C^{L\times N}$. Therefore for every $W\in\mathbb C^{L\times L}$, $B^\ast(A^\ast WA)B=(AB)^\ast W(AB)=W$. Clearly $A^\ast WA$ is positive semidefinite when $W$ is positive semidefinite.